# Correct ATF for 1968 Mercedes 280s

Tags: automatic-transmission, atf

I need to fill a 1968 Mercedes 280s which has a slow transmission leak and I do not know the right fluid to use. The manual simply says fill with automatic transmission fluid, which isn't very helpful considering how many types there are now.

What ATF should I use?

Comment: There is "generic" automotive ATF ... I'd suspect this is exactly what they are talking about ... however, I agree ... better to *know exactly* what to use rather than guess.

Comment: They used Dexron ATF those years.

Comment: This link may help : https://www.autodoc.co.uk/car-parts/gearbox-oil-and-transmission-oil-11915/mercedes-benz/s-class/s-class-w108-w109

Comment: Thanks @Solar, I tried that link and unfortunately it tells me nothing is available.

Comment: @Moab, I'd take that as an answer if you turn it into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They used Dexron ATF those years, any Dexron ATF will work in your transmission.

Answer (score 1):

From this [link](https://www.ecstuning.com/Mercedes_Benz-1968-280S-Base-L6_2.8L/Drivetrain/Automatic_Transmission/) it seems you have a few options with the suggested being Mobil ATF D/M. Hope this helps!